# MATLAB STL 3D modelling from IMU Data

Tags: matlab, 3d, rotation, euler-angles

I am trying to upload an STL file to MATLAB and be able to manipulate it but can't find the best way to do it.

What I am trying to do is import an STL a file of a hand tool and be able to rotate the 3D image by giving it roll, pitch and yaw angles. The whole system will involve a live read out from an IMU which calculates these angles (going to use a 9 axis IMU - 9250 and hope to incorporate space movement into this but that's progress for another day) which will feed into a function which alters the orientation of the model made from the STL to show in real time how the body is moving. Its important to note the body is fixed so no points can move relative to each other (simplifying the problem).

Currently I have not got far but have modeled the STL fixed in space:

```
model = createpde(3);
importGeometry(model,'Test_model.stl');
pdegplot(model);
```

This will plot the STL file. The model is made up of a certain number of faces and vertices which can be plotted but I cannot see a way of manipulating these. I figure that there should be some way of converting this to a 3D matrix of points in x,y,z which I can mulitply by a rotation vector to give a new position rotated by the three angles.

```
Rx = rotx(psi);
Ry = roty(theta);
Rz = rotz(phi);
R = Rx*Ry*Rz;
```

Then multiply the model by this and update the plot.

I will also need a way of offsetting all points by certain values to be able to change the point of rotation (where the IMU is placed). I figure once I get the coordinates in a matrix then I can offset them all by certain values in each direction x, y and z.

Can anyone help with this, I have been looking for similar projects but I have not been able to find anything with good code explanations as of yet. The way I am proposing is only my idea, if there is an easier method then please say. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I do not have comment privileges so this may not seem like a complete answer.

I've done exactly this type of thin in MATLAB for other research but had to write my own data parsers as I do not have any tool boxes, or importGeometry() didn't exist at the time.  The STL is structured as a list of triangles each with a normal and three vertices.  I'd ask you, after importing STL what is the data format?  An array of positions, a struct or object?  Also, what s/w was used to make it.  The gmsh format is easier to work with as it gives you a reduced list of points and lists of connections between them based on what simplex contains the points.

If the output of importGeometry is a struct with the full data set then you will have repeated data and need to (1) parse the struct, (2) delete duplicates, (3) stack the results in a 3-by-N or N-by-3 matrix, then operate on this result with the rotation matrix and update plots.

You haven't really asked a specific question but I hope that my comments were helpful.